# Return last 5 characters of a URL before parameters

Tags: javascript, url

I have searched for some similar questions but didn't find an answer so here I am.

I am currently using this to get the last 5 characters from a URL

```
    function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var lastfive = url.substr(url.length - 5);     
  return lastfive; 
}
```

So when my url is **domain.com/folder/post-author-45210** it returns 45210. Now what i want to know is when the url is

**domain.com/folder/post-author-45210?code=98054874**

Will it still return 45210 that I need or return 54874 instead ?

Thank you

EDIT : Solved it with this one :

```
function() {
  var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
  var lastfive = url.substr(url.length - 5);     
  return lastfive; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.href` will return the full URL.

However, you can access as a string just the path using
`window.location.pathname`
So something like this should work:

```
function() {
  var url = window.location.pathname;
  var lastfive = url.substr(url.length - 5);     
  return lastfive; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation for window.location.href https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

It will return the last 5 characters so 54874. I think you should have tried using console.log before asking here, though.

Comment: Okay thank you, it just that i am not a dev and I know nothing about it, so trying to know from you guys.